# m_Entries is undefined

Tags: opengl, animation, skeletal-animation, assimp

I am following [this tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html) and this guy puts in his code m_Entries and doesn't explain it at all at least I think. So any one who has done skeletal animation show me what he is talking about by m_Entries.

Comment: Please describe the problem at hand, without requiring us to visit a 3rd party site. This site is for precise question, where we give precise answers.

Answer (score 4):

Note that this is the 38th tutorial in a [series](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/). If you go back to [part 22](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial22/tutorial22.html), you can see m_Entries is defined as follows:

> The m_Entries member of the Mesh class is a vector of the MeshEntry
>   struct where each structure corresponds to one mesh structure in the
>   aiScene object. That structure contains the vertex buffer, index
>   buffer and the index of the material.

This is the type of answer you could easily have found by yourself by at least skimming earlier parts of the tutorial, or, worst case, downloading the full source from the link above and looking in `mesh.cpp` and `mesh.h` to see how it's used.